# Rails 5 scope like multiple partial strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Say I have a scope like this:

```
scope :by_templates, ->(t) { joins(:template).where('templates.label ~* ?', t) }
```

How can I retrieve multiple templates with `t` like so?

```
Document.first.by_templates(%w[email facebook])
```

This code returns this error.

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type record
   LINE 1: ...template_id" WHERE "documents"."user_id" = $1 AND (templates...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL allows you to apply a boolean valued operator to an entire array of values using the [`op any(array_expr)` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16):

> **9.23.3. ANY/SOME (array)**
>
> ```
> expression operator ANY (array expression)
> expression operator SOME (array expression)
> ```
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given `operator`, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of `ANY` is “true” if any true result is obtained. The result is “false” if no true result is found (including the case where the array has zero elements).

PostgreSQL also supports the [array constructor syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) for creating arrays:

```
array[value, value, ...]
```

Conveniently, ActiveRecord will expand a placeholder as a comma-delimited list when the value is an array.

Putting these together gives us:

```
scope :by_templates, ->(templates) { joins(:template).where('templates.label ~* any(array[?])', templates) }
```

As an aside, if you're using the case-insensitive regex operator (`~*`) as a case-insensitive comparison (i.e. no real regex pattern matching going on) then you might want to use `upper` instead:

```
# Yes, this class method is still a scope.
def self.by_templates(templates)
  joins(:template).where('upper(templates.label) = any(array[?])', templates.map(&:upcase) }
end
```

Then you could add an index to `templates` on `upper(label)` to speed things up and avoid possible issues with stray regex metacharacters in the `templates`. I tend to use upper case for this sort of thing because of oddities lie `'ß'.upcase` being `'SS'` but `'SS'.downcase` being `'ss'`.